# Get KeyValue from Cloudformation Output with Python Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I am trying to use Boto3 to print out the instance private IP address from a Cloudformation stack Output. It should be a fairly straightforward process. However my code just refuse to work.

The Outputs section of the describe_stacks response is below:

```
{'OutputKey': 'EC2IP', 'OutputValue': '192.168.10.10', 'Description': 'Web Server IP Address'},
{'OutputKey': 'ImageID', 'OutputValue': 'ami-0888888888888', 'Description': 'Web Server Image ID'}
```

I have tested my code below. It prints out nothing.

```
import boto3
cf_client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
stackname = 'test-instance-stack'

response = cf_client.describe_stacks(StackName=stackname)
outputs = response["Stacks"][0]["Outputs"]
   for output in outputs:
        keyName = output["OutputKey"]
        if keyName is "EC2IP":
            print(output["OutputValue"])
```

Though if I try

```
print(keyName)
```

It does printout `EC2IP` and `ImageID`
So keyName in this case should match EC2IP and then print out the IP. But somehow I get nothing...

Comment: Here is a explanation for the difference bewteen **==** and **is**. The **==** operator compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality. Whereas **is** operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if keyName is "EC2IP":
```

Use:

```
if keyName == "EC2IP":
```